# Want to retrieve metadata and Meta contents from other website link

Tags: jquery, asp.net, wcf, metadata, meta-tags

I am working on a social Network project.
Which is based on asp.net 4.0 ,WCF and JQuery.
In my project there is a module for extract the metadata and meta contains from the 
other website URL.
Example- If i will give URL then it will retrieve the details-

**URL**- http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com

**Meta data-** The Times of India: Latest News India, World & Business News, Cricket
 & Sports, Bollywood

**Meta content-** Times of India brings the Latest & Top Breaking News on Politics and
 Current Affairs in India & around the World, Cricket, Sports,
 Business, Bollywood News and Entertainment, Science, Technology,
 Health & Fitness news & opinions from leading columnists.

I have search a lot but not able to get any kind of clue
Can any one help me by send some code or by some useful link i can get some references or information.

Answer (score 1):

Now days, web sites don't scrape data from other sites - they syndicate.  That is, they share the information through an interface that is easily consumed.  There are a few techniques, but a common format is using RSS that presents the data in XML format for you to consume.

That particular website offers a series of [RSS feeds](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rss.cms).  However, remember to read the terms of [use](http://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/rss_index.cms#tou) as there may be restrictions on its usage.  Of course, you can still go with scraping, but there are laws against claiming copyrighted material as your own.